# Cross-compiling a loadable kernel module for Android

Tags: android, clang, llvm, cross-compiling, kernel-module

I'm trying to install the [LiME](https://github.com/504ensicsLabs/LiME) tool for memory dumps in Android. LiME is implemented through a loadable kernel module, which, as I understand, forces me to prepare and compile the kernel for it. Their [installation guide](https://github.com/504ensicsLabs/LiME/tree/master/doc) mentions:

> Next we have to prepare our kernel source for our module.
>
> `$ cd $KSRC_PATH`
>
> `$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$CC_PATH/arm-eabi- modules_prepare`

The problem is the guide adopts an obsolete toolchain (Android NDK < r16). The newer versions renamed the binaries and abandoned `gcc` support, among other changes. So I did some research and came up with this command for NDK r25 with arch x86_64 and `clang`:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CC=clang CLANG_TRIPLE=x86_64-linux-gnu- CROSS_COMPILE=$CC_PATH/x86_64-linux-android30 modules_prepare
```

However, it seems the compiler prefixes files it should not, e.g.:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /home/gabrielrebello/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android30ld: not found // (but /home/gabrielrebello/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/ld exists)
```

To be honest, I don't even understand why the compiler is looking for `ld` instead of `lld` if I'm compiling with `clang`. I guess I'm missing some configuration. As you can see, I'm a newbie in this subject, so a detailed explanation would help a lot.

The kernel source I'm using is `android-msm-coral-4.14-android13` (obtained [here](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-kernels)).

Thanks.